# Passing variable for ajax to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

```
<select type="category" id="x1">
  <option value="country">Country</option>
  <option value="city">City</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#x1').on('change',function(){
 var x1 = $(this).val();

  if(x1){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajaxData.php',
      data: {'x1'},
      success: function(data){
      console.log("success");
      }
    }); 
   }
  });
});

//script.php
<?php
  $var1 = $_POST['x1'];
  print_r ($var1);
?>
```

I am trying to get value from `select` (either country or city) and pass on to 'script.php'.
Newbie, so excuse for any silly mistakes.

Comment: For one, [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) doesn't have a "type", yet alone "category".

Comment: it does however need a name attribute!

Comment: Also, you are passing the string `'x1'` to your PHP code, not the value of the variable `x1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` parameter must be a `key:value` object, so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajaxData.php',
  data: {x1: x1},  // here first x1 is a key name, second x1 is selected value
  success: function(data){
  console.log("success");
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, thnx, it solved my problem.

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer if it helps.